# How to set generated additional values in pydantic response_model?

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I the following problem but don't know how to solve it:
How can I add a generated Id in the job.py and set it to the value job_id in JobResponse?

This is my function job.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from models import JobResponse, JobRequest

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/job', response_model=JobResponse)
async def create_user(job: JobRequest):
    id = return_id_from_database
    return job
```

models.py:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

class JobRequest(BaseModel):
    job_name: Optional[str] = None

class JobResponse(BaseModel):
    job_id: Optional[str] = None
    job_name: Optional[str] = None
```

Comment: Have you tried job.id = id ? See https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/

Comment: yes, i have. when I enter job.job_id pydantic return: AttributeError: 'JobRequest' object has no attribute 'job_id'

Comment: Then  you could try `job = new JobResponse(**job.to_dict(), job_id=id)`. Though, I would suggest you to make `JobResponse` inherit from `JobRequest` since they share attributes. If this works, I'll write a more extensive answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, your suggested solution works for me. 
I found it also in the documentation here: 
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/extra-models/?h=+key+#unwrapping-a-dict-and-extra-keywords

Answer (score 0):

As promised in the comments, my suggestion was useful and thus I'm writing a proper answer for others as well.

The solution was rather simple, as `Fastapi` expected the function `create_user` to return an object serializable to `JSON` and that complies to the definition of the `Pydantic` model declared as return value.

## job.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from models import JobResponse, JobRequest

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/job', response_model=JobResponse)
async def create_user(job: JobRequest):
    id = return_id_from_database
    return new JobResponse(**job.to_dict(), job_id=id)
```

## models.py

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

class JobRequest(BaseModel):
    job_name: Optional[str] = None

class JobResponse(JobRequest):
    job_id: Optional[str] = None
```